# How to get all network requests using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console, network-traffic

I'm looking for something similar to window.performance.getEntries() which would allow to get the status and perhaps the response of all network requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of network requests done by HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621084/how-to-get-list-of-network-requests-done-by-html)