# Is it possible to get HTTP response (not just list or resources provided by Resource Timing API) by JS?

Tags: javascript, http, httpresponse, client-side

Is it possible to get data which we see in the tab Network in browser using JS? I don't mean XMLHTTPrequest, just the common request some page. Particularly I'm interested of HTTP response for requested resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of network requests done by HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621084/how-to-get-list-of-network-requests-done-by-html)

Comment: What will be potential response type of the request so made? e.g. `text/html` or `text/plain` or `text/javascript`

Answer (score 0):

You can try Service Workers API: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

It's a new API that's not available in Safari and Edge yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers