# Get access to or acquire files on Network tab in developer console

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Is possible to access or acquire the files that are passed to the client from the server, the files displayed on the Network tab in the developer console?

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20621084/7543162) that suggests obtaining the logs may be possible with browser extension technology, but it is a really old question and answer. I am also interested in obtaining the files, not the logs.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** you can do it by using [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).

**Service Worker** is a script which runs on your browser **separated from your website**. It allows to run background javascript functions which is not need any user interaction (Logs / Analytics).

And

**Service worker is a programmable network proxy, allowing you to control how network requests from your page are handled.**

[Learn More Features of Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)

---

Sample Service worker which will be activated for all `/sw.js` requests from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com)

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

> **NOTE :** You **cannot** intercept other website's traffic using service workers. That is browser level control, For that you need to use **browser level extensions** or **packet sniffers** such as **Wireshark** or **Brupsuite**.

Comment: beautiful. can you add a bit more info, then ill mark this as the answer!!

Comment: can i use service workers to intercept and obtain the resources from a website that is not my own ???

Comment: No cannot intercept other sites.

Comment: Your question has no sense, If it is possible any site can spy on you!