# Capture network files or client's network requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, browser, electron

Is there a way to capture the files being served to the client, say with an Electron App's `BrowserView` or perhaps a browser extension?

For example, say you visit a website, whereby a font is served to the client in order to be displayed on that website, is there any way as a client or otherwise to capture that file?

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20621084/7543162) that suggests obtaining the network logs may be possible with browser extension technology, but it is a really old question, and I am interested in obtaining the files instead of the logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you want to capture a file programatically? or just manually? But then again If a font or static file is served by a server it will have an url, you can just capture the url then download the file.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty programmatically of course, otherwise id just use the dev console. how do i capture the requests/responses with JS tho?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty it may. ill have to take a closer look tomo. thanks. is there a way to capture that info without puppeteer or whatever its called?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty so what im doing in my electron app is creating a `webview` in which the user can navigate the web. is there a better way to capture all of the requests/responses than puppeteer??

Comment: @AritraChakraborty you mind taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816741/capture-webview-requests-and-responses)?