# Javascript listener for all browser XHR requests to match url

Tags: javascript

I there a way - in vanilla javascript - to listen for all network request of the browser and match if a given url was used in the request (request url).
I would like for example to listen if the browser loads for example "https://www.google.com" and alert the user. Ideally it should be cross-browser. Any tip is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of network requests done by HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621084/how-to-get-list-of-network-requests-done-by-html)

Comment: Yes and no. I don't understand how to get the request url