# Is it possible to watch over XHR/Fetch requests happening in the browser?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to react to some events that are triggered by a 3rd party on my site.
Those events are Fetch/XHR requests, I'd like to be notified when a "watched" request happens (I assume I would watch them based on the "Request URL"), and I would like to read its request/response headers and payload.

I've never seen that being done before, is it even possible?

The browser is aware of all requests happening, but I'm uncertain whether we can read this, can we?

Eventually, I hope to achieve a watcher that would trigger my own code when some endpoints have been called, while re-using the data sent by those requests. I'm hoping to both detect **WHEN** a particular endpoint is called, and **WHAT** the response is, so that I can use it for my own needs (without needing to perform yet another identical request)

I'm not sure if reading the data will be possible, I found out that reacting to fetch requests is possible with the help of Resource Timing (see https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/)

Comment: please read the guide, how to ask a good question at stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've added more details.

Comment: Sorry to say but someone voted down your question because of not meeting the proper criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using the WebRequest built-in library. The following example is specific to the Chrome Extension runtime, but something similar is doable for browsers, too.

> For Chrome Extensions, it needs to run as a **Service Worker** (e.g: background.js)*

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  (requestHeadersDetails) => {
    console.log('requestHeadersDetails', requestHeadersDetails);
  },
  {
    urls: ['https://*'],
  },
  [
    'requestHeaders',
    'extraHeaders',
  ],
);
```

See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest and https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeSendHeaders (both are very similar)

I didn't find a way to re-use the data that were fetched, though.
But at least I'm notified when a request is sent.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can create decorator-function for fetch:

```
const origFetch = fetch;

window.fetch = function(...args) {
  console.log(args);
  return origFetch.apply(this, args);
}
```

Also you can create decorator for `Response.prototype.json` function.

Comment: I'm not sure what function would use the code (fetch, or something else). Also, it wouldn't be possible to do that if I were to write a Chrome Extension. The idea is good and might work in some cases but isn't exactly what I'm looking for, although it has the advantage of being used to both detect the call and pass down the response data.